# How to repopulate select2 result

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Good day,

I am using Select2 plugin for my project. I used it in email function in the recipient text. At first once the user type something it will fetch from the database then it will add the new options inside my `select` . My problem is how can i repopulate the result of select2 rather showing of no result.

Below is my html code

```
<div class="form-group" id="div_select2">
     <select class="form-control select2" id="select2_email" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Select a Group" style="width: 100%;">
          <option></option>
          <option value="group" data-id="1">Pulse Asia Group</option>
          <option value="group" data-id="2">Unite Group</option>
          <option value="group" data-id="3">RCBC Group</option>
     </select>
</div><!-- /.form-group -->
```

And my script example below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#div_select2').on('keyup','.select2-search__field',function(){
            keyme = $(this);
            $(this).attr('added','current');
            console.log($('#select2-select2_email-results li').eq(0));
            if( typeof $('#select2-select2_email-results li').eq(0).attr('id') == 'undefined'){ //select2 no result
                l = '<option class="added-opt" value="group" data-id="">'+$(this).val()+'</option>';
                $('#select2_email').append(l);
                //i want to trigger the repopulate of results here so the user can choose dynamic results
                }
          });
      });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used select2 ajax option. it can get data using ajax method.